# How to Merge Rows in Pandas DF based on Filter Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, string, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe where there are a number of columns. In some cases the rows are duplicated with slight variations in some of the columns eg:

| NAME | UNIQUE CODE | COUNTRIES | ATTRBITUE | ANOTHER ATTRIBUTE | NUMBERS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | XYZABC | UA EU SA | X | DELTA | 2 |
| Name | XYZABC | CH | Y | ALPHA | 3 |

What I want to do is concatenate the above to get:

| NAME | UNIQUE CODE | COUNTRIES | ATTRIBUTE | ANOTHER ATTRIBUTE | NUMBERS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | XYZABC | UA EU SA CH | X Y | DELTA ALPHA | 5 |

How do I identify duplicate rows based on say the 'UNIQUE CODE' and concatenate the other row values under the different columns with the exception of the UNIQUE CODE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` `agg` and `agg` function can take dictionary of column name as key and an aggregation function as value.

- For NAME column, you are taking only 1 value => `first` (or `last`).
- For NUMBERS column, you are getting the sum of the column. => `sum`
- For other columns, you are getting concat of strings => `' '.join`

So, you need this dictionary to pass for `agg` function.

```
{
  'NAME': 'first',
  'NUMBERS': 'sum',
  'COUNTRIES': ' '.join,
  'ATTRIBUTE': ' '.join,
  'ANOTHER ATTRIBUTE': ' '.join
}
```

You can pass this hardcoded dictionary directly to the `agg` function.  Or you can do this a little bit more compact like this.

```py
join_col = ['COUNTRIES', 'ATTRIBUTE', 'ANOTHER ATTRIBUTE']
(df.groupby('UNIQUE CODE', as_index=False)
 .agg({
       **{'NAME': 'first', 'NUMBERS': 'sum'},
       **{x: ' '.join for x in join_col]}
 })
)
```